# Given $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} (f(x) + \frac{1}{|f(x)|})=0$ find $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Given $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} (f(x) + \frac{1}{|f(x)|})=0$ find $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)$.

If I was able to prove that $f(x)$ has a real limit that is not equal to $0$, then the question becomes trivial. However, I could not prove that it has a real limit.